# How do I include libsdn and portaudio in a C project?

Tags: c, linux, audio, portaudio

#### The project

The "project" im currently working on is a **tui wav player**. **I'm in the first stage where i want to read and play a wav song/sound.**

Please consider that I started using C in 4 weeks ago, so **I am a total newbie**.

I' m not using any IDE, and `cc` to compile (`cc main.c -o main -lm`)

#### Things I did

I dowloaded **portaudio via yay/pacman**, I downloaded **libsnd** **source** from [here](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/), installed with the help of the documentation (./configure && make && make install).

The libsnd sources are in the same folder as my main.c code.

Output of  `ls -a`

```
 .    c-econio  'Goran Bregović - Kalashnikov.mp3'   kalasnikow.wav      main.c       test.c
 ..   .git      'Goran Bregović - Kalashnikov.wav'   libsndfile-1.0.28   random.mp3
```

**c-econio** and **libsndfile-1.0.28** are **dir's** (library's) that i want to use (econio will be used later on). As previously mentioned **portaudio** is installed via package manager.

I have no idea if `#inlude <portauido>` is working, cause i dont know how to test it without libsnd.

#### The main question

How do i include portaudio and libsnd into this code and how do i test it? Do i have to add something to the compiler (cc)?
Im using linux.

#### The code

main.c

```c
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <portaudio.h>

int listwav() {
    int i = 1;
     DIR *d;
    struct dirent *entry;
    d = opendir("."); // Megnyitom az éppenleges DIR-t.
    if (d) {
        while ((entry = readdir(d)) != NULL) {  // Ameddig van file + mp3 kiiratás. 
            if (strlen(entry->d_name) > 4 && strcmp(entry->d_name + strlen(entry->d_name) - 4, ".wav") == 0) {
              printf("\t%d %s\n",i, entry->d_name);
              i++; 
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return (0);
}

void play(){ // play audio "ffplay -v 0 -nodisp -autoexit"
  printf("What to play? \n");
  listwav();
  // system("playerctl play");
}

void stop(){
  printf("Stopped\n");
  // system("playerctl stop");
}

int chose(){
  int chosen = 0;    
  
  printf("Choose what to do:\n 1.Play\n 2.Stop\n 3.Exit\n Chosen: "); scanf("%d", &chosen);
  while (chosen != 3){
    switch (chosen) {
      case 1: play(); break;
      case 2: stop(); break;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

 /// -----
 int main(){
   chose();

 }
```

EDIT:
Unupdated version of the folder im using: https://github.com/Lolis4TheWin/mpc3

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to _link_ the libraries to your executable. Can you include your makefile in your question?

Comment: Make file? You mean the `libsnd` make file or my code's? Cause i dont know how to create a make file and I dont have one.

Comment: How are you compiling and linking your code?

Comment: "I' m not using any IDE, and cc to compile (cc main.c -o main -lm)" The fist section.

Comment: If you build and install the library, there is no need to put it into your own source folder. That only clutters the folder. Keep things separate. After you did `make install` from that lib, the generated lib should be in your library folder and you don't need to keep the sources around your own project.

Comment: And then i just include with `#include <>`?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. After `make install` was executed successfully, the headers and libraries should be able to be used as shown in the library's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out!

### Download and make the librabry

1. Download the source
2. Read the installation manual inside the source file
3. Do what it says (`./configure; make ; make install`)
4. You can delete the source, the library is in your `/usr/local/lib` dir.

### Compile the code

A) option

`gcc -lsndfile main.c -o main -lm && ./main`  is what i had to use when compiling.

After `-l` the library name comes. `-o` stands for output file and `-lm` stands for some library to that i had to include cause of linux. (I think, not based information.)

And I had to include the librars like this:

```c
#include <sndfile>
#include <portaudio>
```

B) option

Is to link the library with path inside `""`

```c
#include "usr/local/lib/libsndfila.a"
```